# Write a Domain frequency 'categorize' function which accepts array of URLS and returns expected output

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Input:

```
const urls = [
    'www.google.com',
    'www.yahoo.com',
    'xyz.www.google.com',
    'abc.xyz.www.google.com',
    'google.com',
    'yahoo.com',
    'news.yahoo.com',
    'abc.news.yahoo.com',
    'abc.xyz.www.google.com',
    'www.yahoo.com',
    'google.com',
];
categorize(urls);
```

The above categorize function should return below output.
For instance, 'www.google.com' is occuring in 'www.google.com', 'xyz.www.google.com', 'abc.xyz.www.google.com' etc.
'google.com' is occuring in 'google.com', 'www.google.com', 'xyz.www.google.com', 'abc.xyz.www.google.com' etc.

Expected Output:

```
{
 "google.com": 6,
 "yahoo.com": 5,
 "www.google.com": 4,
 "www.yahoo.com": 2,
 "news.yahoo.com": 2,
 "xyz.www.google.com": 3,
 "abc.news.yahoo.com": 1,
 "abc.xyz.www.google.com": 2,
 "com": 11
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll first need to create an object, for example `const categorized = {}`

Then iterate through urls with a for loop (or forEach).

For each url, you'll need to find all possible domains. There are probably a few good ways to accomplish this.

For each domain, add the key to the object if it doesn't yet exist and set the value to 1. If the key already exists, then add 1 to the value.